# RNDateTimePicker is not scaling on bigger screen devices

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

This is my component where I am importing RNDateTimePicker directly from the library and using on my landing screen:

```
import { Platform, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { styles } from "./LandingScreen.style";

import RNDateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import PrimaryHeader from "../../../components/primaryHeader/PrimaryHeader";

const LandingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaStyle}>
      <PrimaryHeader />
      <RNDateTimePicker
        mode="time"
        value={new Date()}
        display={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "spinner" : "default"}
        style={{ flex: 1 }} // Apply custom styles here
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default LandingScreen;
```

Tablet screen output:

[image]